# ADFS Single Logout both OAuth/OpenID and SAML federated clients

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on

I am trying to set up ADFS as a single sign-on identity provider for various apps. Some of these apps work with only SAML identity providers while others only work with OAuth/OpenID.

It seems like I can add both of these into my ADFS server; the apps requiring SAML get added as a "relying party trust" and the apps requiring OAuth/OpenID get added in the "Application Groups" page and receive a client ID/secret.

Now, I would like to securely implement single logout. This should cover both cases where someone voluntarily logs out, and also where someone's session is forcibly logged out (for example, account is disabled). Would the user logging out of, say, an OAuth authenticated application (via https://adfs-server/adfs/oauth2/logout) also result in logout requests being sent to any possible applications they are logged in via SAML? How about the reverse (logout initiated at an application logged in via SAML)?